# How to redirect to a url which is as a result of execute function in php

Tags: php, url, redirect, sms

This is code given to me by a SMS API provider through which I can send SMS to a specified number.

```
include './sendsms.php';
$sendsms=new sendsms("http://alerts.htht.com/api/web2sms.php",
    "74980pky627vdfdgs5f", "SIDEMO");
$sendsms->send_sms("94********",
    "Click here to buy the product. https://www.ttyu.com/demo/tbuy .Thank You",
    "http://www.yourdomainname.domain/yourdlrpage&msgid=XX", "xml");
```

I have placed this code in **trigger.php**. As I open the page **www.fsf.com/trigger.php**, I am getting

> `http://alerts.htht.com/api/web2sms.php?workingkey=74980pky627vdfgds5f&sender=SIDEMO&to=94********&message=Click+here+to+buy+the+product.+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ttyu.com%2Fdemo%2Ftbuy+.Thank+You&type=xml&dlr_url=http://www.yourdomainname.domain/yourdlrpage&msgid=XX`

as output, but no SMS is sent.  If I use the above url in a browser, the SMS is send.

So is there any way I can redirect to this link as the page loads, or run this url? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think as per your requirement you have only one work in this page i.e to send sms.

So I suggest the following code :

```
$x = $sendsms->send_sms("94********",
    "Click here to buy the product. https://www.ttyu.com/demo/tbuy .Thank You",
    "http://www.yourdomainname.domain/yourdlrpage&msgid=XX", "xml");
```

header('Location:'.$x);
exit;